# What are the main primary sources for the life and times of Shah Ismail I?

Tags: historiography, literature, persia, islamic-history, biography

The Encyclopaedia Iranica seems mostly to base its account on Khvandamir, Hasan Beg Rumlu and to a lesser extent Khonji. Which of these (or any other primary source) has the most extensive treatment of his rise (including background on the Qizilbash) and reign?

Also, are there notable poetic narratives wholly or partially about his life?